# What's the difference of IsolatedStorageSettings between wp7 and wp8?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I stored some keys into `IsolatedStorageSettings`, they all work very well on WP7.

Now, I've upgraded my app to WP8, but with the same `IsolatedStorageSettings`, and now all settings keys are missing.

I guess I'm doing something wrong in the deserialization of `IsolatedStorageSettings`? Has anyone else experienced this or know a workaround?

Comment: There should be no differences. Can you please provide an example of what you're doing that recreates the problem.

Comment: also, how did you update your app to WP8? Does it mean you have two apps installed side by side on your machine? A WP8-only app and a WP7-only app are considered two different apps on the machine, and thus do not share the same storage.

Comment: Thanks all of you, I pinpointed the problem, this is because I updated the stored object's namespace in wp8, this way, although the class didn't have any change, but IsolatedStorageSettings still can't deserialize it.